# MacOS/Windows - How to extract specific .json file from multiple zips and renaming the .json file as folder it was extracted from

Tags: json, macos, directory, extract, unzip

I am dealing with cuckoo sandbox exported data having `report.json` file under each zip file.

eg > 123456.zip each zip has the file in zipfile/reports/report.json

I have multiple zip files in a folder. I want to have those zip files to be named as `zipfilename.json`. I have tried many ways but to fail, here's the code I am trying:

```
#! /bin/bash

mkdir -p "DESTDIR"
for i in *.zip ; do
         unzip "$i" $i/reports/report.json -d "DESTDIR"
         mv "DESTDIR/reports/report.json" "DESTDIR/$(basename "$i" .zip)_THEFILE"
done
```

All I get is this output showing that the file does not exist:

```
(base) s@Sais-MBP Downloads % sh script.sh 
Archive:  1959098.zip
caution: filename not matched:  1959098.zip/reports/report.json
mv: rename DESTDIR/THEFILE to DESTDIR/1959098_THEFILE: No such file or directory
Archive:  1959100.zip
caution: filename not matched:  1959100.zip/reports/report.json
mv: rename DESTDIR/THEFILE to DESTDIR/1959100_THEFILE: No such file or directory
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I cannot make any progress for the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I took help from a friend and he gave me the answer to it as I have done the whole script wrong

```
    #! /bin/bash
#
# save this file as test.sh
#
mkdir -p "DESTDIR"
for ZIPFILE in *.zip ; do
    NAME="${ZIPFILE%.*}"
    mkdir -p "DESTDIR/$NAME"
    unzip -j $ZIPFILE reports/report.json -d "DESTDIR/$NAME/"
    mv "DESTDIR/$NAME/report.json" "DESTDIR/$NAME.json"
done
```